# What is wrong with my power supply design schematic in Proteus

Tags: power-supply, simulation, proteus

I have re-created a Lab Power Supply design from the EEVBlog YouTube channel (see image 1) in Proteus (see image 2).
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
However, when I run the simulation in Proteus, the output voltage is constantly out of range and is in the MegaVolts (see image 3).
[image: Image 3]
Any advice that anyone an provide in relation to what I may have done wrong with capturing the circuit schematic correctly in Proteus would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an initial spike/discontinuity + auto scaling of your Y-axis. Can you step your voltage source from zero?

Comment: @winny Thanks for the prompt response and for the suggestion. I'll look into stepping the voltage source form zero and and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: You are most welcome? 1 mohm series resistance with your voltage source could be an option too.